# Install perl-LWP-Protocol-https package on OEL 6.10

Tags: linux, perl

I wanted to install **perl-LWP-Protocol-https** package on my OEL 6.10 server. I did download the rpm of the same and tried to install it. But it has lot of dependencies. So I did setup repo from https://packages.endpoint.com/ to install the required package. But I am getting below error while installing. Could some one help me ?

```
yum install perl-LWP-Protocol-https*
```

> Loaded plugins:
>   security
>  Setting up Install Process
>   https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/6Server/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] problem making ssl connection
>  Trying other mirror.
>   Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for
>   repository: endpoint.
>  Please verify its path and try again

Answer (score 0):

> install perl-LWP-Protocol-https package on OEL 6.10

The rpm package perl-LWP-Protocol-https seems to origin from a discontinued Suse repo for EL6.

Install the perl module `LWP-Protocol-https` :

```
# yum install perl-IO-Socket-SSL perl-CPAN
# cpan
cpan[1]> install Net::HTTPS 
cpan[2]> install LWP::UserAgent
cpan[3]> install LWP::Protocol::https
```

The install test was done with "Redhat CentOS 6.10".

---

Alternatives for OEL 6.10 : Install **perl-CPAN** with yum. And install "the other modules" with `CPAN`

If no perl-CPAN in the OEL repo, then install CPAN from source https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-2.27.tar.gz

```
cd CPAN-2.27/ && perl Makefile.PL && make
# make install
```

Comment: @kund thanks a lot for the suggestion. But no luck on my OEL 6.10.

Comment: Which package couldn't be installed ? ..... Which commands were used ?